# OpenBMC WebUI update version MANIFEST and publickey

Tags: openbmc

I want to update BMC image via OpenBmc WebUI.

openbmc web will block upload files of the same version

I try to trace code to understand the /upload/image mechanism

It seems to be related to MANIFEST & publickey

Where can I find the openbmc code that handles this part?

Comment: Why don't you just change the version number?

Comment: Because I want to understand the code architecture

Answer (score 0):

You could start tracing the image upload code from [here](https://github.com/openbmc/bmcweb/blob/2205bbf681bfac508a9e985b9581ce9d662db4df/include/image_upload.hpp#L110)

Probably you are seeing the error message [here](https://github.com/openbmc/bmcweb/blob/2205bbf681bfac508a9e985b9581ce9d662db4df/include/image_upload.hpp#L56). I don't use this file upload mechanism, so am not best person to understand the issue. You might want to check on the discord if anyone else has similar issues. Also, having the exact text of the error message is helpful.

I hope this sends you on the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
In addition, I found that MANIFEST seems to be related to the /usr/bin/phosphor-version-software-manager